# Why do I get an authentication error when I pass an axios config object with an authorization token? MERN

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

I am making a small social network application. I came up with a like post route and the user has to be logged in to be able to perform that action, and I have auth middleware that looks like this:

```
const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
  // check header
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;

  if (!authHeader || !authHeader.startsWith('Bearer')) {
    throw new UnauthenticatedError('Authentication invalid');
  }
  const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];

  try {
    const payload = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    req.user = { userId: payload.userId };
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new UnauthenticatedError('Authentication invalid');
  }
};
```

When I pass an object with an authorization token to Axios, I get an error, here is the action.js file:

```
export const likePost = id => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();

    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/v1/post/${id}/like`, config);

    dispatch({ type: POST_LIKE_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    dispatch({
      type: POST_LIKE_FAIL,
      payload: { msg: error.response.data.msg },
    });
  }
};
```

When I open the network tab in the browser, the request tab shows that I forward the headers {Authorization: Bearer .... token} and in response I get error 401.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert with Axios, but [according to the documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosputurl-data-config-1), the `put` method uses `data` as the second argument and `config` as the third.

Maybe try to provide an empty value like `null` or an empty string for the second argument:

```
const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/v1/post/${id}/like`, null, config);
```

Comment: Holyyyy moly i I totally forgot that..... <3